# Как настроить заголовки для DataFrame с read_excel()?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Excel таблица у меня такая:

```
0  |___|___|____|_________|
1    A | B | C  |SS  |SS_1|
   ____|___|____|____|____|
2      |   |    |  D |  E |
   ____|___|____|____|____|
3    1 | 2 | 3  | 4  |  5 |
              ...
```

Мне нужно получить либо такой DataFrame:

```
     A | B | C  |SS  |SS_1|
   ____|___|____|____|____|
     1 | 2 | 3  | 4  |  5 |
```

Либо такой (мне без разницы, какой легче осуществить):

```
     A | B | C  |D   |E   |
   ____|___|____|____|____|
     1 | 2 | 3  | 4  |  5 |
```

Как настроить правильно `read_excel()` и `headers`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

воспользуйтесь параметром [pd.read_excel(..., skiprows=[1])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) для того, чтобы пропустить первую строку после заголовка (т.е. строку с индексом `1`):

```
df = pd.read_excel(..., skiprows=[1])
```

Comment: спасибо, а как работать с другими столбиками?

Comment: @MRO, не понял вопроса, можете уточнить?

Answer (score 1):

Удаление из `DataFrame`.

Для удаления элементов из структуры `DataFrame` также применяется метод `drop()`. Для демонстрации будем использовать объект `df`:

```
>>> df
   color  speed  volume      type  value
0    red     56      80    circle      7
1  green     24      65    square      7
2   blue     65      50  triangle      7

>>> df_new = df.drop([0])
>>> df_new
   color  speed  volume      type  value
1  green     24      65    square      7
2   blue     65      50  triangle      7
```

Если необходимо модифицировать саму структуру `df`, то укажите
дополнительно параметр `inplace=True`:

```
>>> df.drop([0], inplace=True)
>>> df
   color  speed  volume      type  value
1  green     24      65    square      7
2   blue     65      50  triangle      7
```